# Get Name interface of network with ansible

Tags: ansible, ovirt

I want to deploy an ovirt template with Ansible, but the problem is that when I want to apply the cloud-init the template displays a different network interface file name every time, that is,

sometimes it is eth0, other times ens33 etc. How could I get this information to be able to apply the cloud init correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Explore all the facts returned by your host with `ansible -i inventory.ini your_host -m setup`..`ansible_default_ipv4.interface` might be a good guess,  You should be able to find the exact match your are looking for. `ansible_interfaces` is also a good variable to look at. You will probably need to find your way.

Comment: The problem is that I have no connection to the machine and before that I have to launch the cloud init against the corresponding interface

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

How about the ovirt_nic_info module?

If you need to gather data there are many ovirt _info modules.

If you have further issues/questions you can open an issue on 
https://github.com/ovirt/ovirt-ansible-collection

```
- ovirt_nic_info:
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
    vm: centos8
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.ovirt_nics[0].reported_devices[0].name }}"
```